# Add list of tables and figures in RMarkdown (table of content) that hyperlinks to the figures/tables in the document

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, kable, tableofcontents

Using this simple RMarkdown example.  How can I generate a list at the beginning of the document that would serve as a table of content; that includes the four tables/figures in the correct order.  And, each title name in the list would work as a hyperlink and brings you to the right output in a click.

````
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars, echo=F}
kableExtra::kable(cars[1:5,], caption='1. one')
kableExtra::kable(cars[2:3,], caption='2. two')
```

```{r pressure, fig.cap='3. three', echo=FALSE, fig.topcaption=T}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r cars2, echo=F}
kableExtra::kable(cars[6:8,], caption='4. four')
```
````

Comment: This may help you: https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/add-a-generated-table-of-contents-anywhere-in-rmarkdown/

Comment: I often use captioner to generate a list of figures and list of tables.  But these are not hyperlinked: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/captioner/vignettes/using_captioner.html